# How to get the current String Value from array in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, google-maps, nsarray

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to get current value of string from array.

My code is like this

```
loginStatusHS = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [myNSMDatalatetudeFromServer mutableBytes] length:[myNSMDatalatetudeFromServer length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"loginStatus =%@",loginStatusHS);
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:loginStatusHS error:&parseError];
    NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY = %@",xmlDictionary);
    recordResultHS = [xmlDictionary[@"success"] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)recordResultHS);
    NSDictionary* Address=[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
    NSLog(@"Address Dict = %@",Address);
    NSDictionary *new =[Address objectForKey:@"soap:Body"];
    NSLog(@"NEW DICT =%@",new);
    NSDictionary *LoginResponse=[new objectForKey:@"HS_GetResponse"];
    NSLog(@"Login Response DICT =%@",LoginResponse);
    NSDictionary *LoginResult=[LoginResponse objectForKey:@"HS_GetResult"];
    NSLog(@"Login Result =%@",LoginResult);
    if(LoginResult.count>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Login Result = %@",LoginResult);
        NSLog(@"Login Result Dict =%@",LoginResult);
        NSString *teststr =[[NSString alloc] init];
        teststr =[LoginResult objectForKey:@"text"];
        NSLog(@"Test String Value =%@",teststr);
        NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];
        NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        responseletetudedict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Latetude Dictionary =%@",responseletetudedict);
        idlatetudearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        idlatetudearray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"City"];

        NameHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NameHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Name"];
        AddressHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        AddressHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Address"];
        FacilitiesHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        FacilitiesHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Facilities"];
        PhoneNoHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        PhoneNoHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Phoneno"];
        FaxnoHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        FaxnoHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Faxno"];
        LatitudeHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        LatitudeHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Latitude"];
        LongitudeHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        LongitudeHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Longitude"];
        TypeHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        TypeHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Type"];

        for (int i=0; i<NameHSArray.count; i++) {
            double LatitudeDouble = [LatitudeHSArray[i] doubleValue];
            double LongitudeDouble = [LongitudeHSArray[i] doubleValue];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LatitudeDouble, LongitudeDouble);
            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
            marker.title = NameHSArray[i];
            marker.snippet=AddressHSArray[i];
            userData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NameHSArray[i], AddressHSArray[i],FacilitiesHSArray[i], PhoneNoHSArray[i],FaxnoHSArray[i], TypeHSArray[i], nil];
            marker.userData = userData;

            if([TypeHSArray[i] isEqualToString:@"ESIC"])
            {
                marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapicon2.png"];
            }
            else
            {
                marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapicon1.png"];
            }
            GMSCameraUpdate *zoomCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate zoomIn];
            [mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:zoomCamera];

            marker.map = mapView;

        }
```

[image]

Add in the Image when I click on Nobel Hospital I call the delegate

```
  - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    // your click action

    StringAddress =  marker.snippet;
    StringName = marker.title;

    NSLog(@"Address=%@",StringAddress);
    NSLog(@"Name= %@",StringName);

    lblNamepopup.text=StringName;
    lblAddresspopup.text=StringAddress;

    NSLog(@"User Data Array = %@",userData);

    viewpopup.hidden=NO;
    viewpopup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        viewpopup.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        // do something once the animation finishes, put it here
    }];
}
```

Hear in this delegate I need to get the current name of string address.But hear I am getting the Last value means the string get override. How can I get the value which I have click from array. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: For each lines like these: `TypeHSArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; TypeHSArray=[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Type"];` The alloc/init is useless, and usually it's not a mutable one. Name your var starting with a lower case. Why do you want to have multiples arrays? It's harder to keep them synced.

Comment: @Larme All array contain different value thats why I used multiple array.My array is dynamic thats why I used Mutable Array.

Comment: You didn't understood: if `[responseletetudedict valueForKey:@"Type"]` is a `NSArray` and not a `NSMutableArray`, `[TypeHSArray addObject:something]` will crash. Then you have multiple array, where you may have only one "main", because what happens if Longitude & Latitude arrays are desync? All bad thing. I think that you should do a smarter parsing.

Comment: @Larme I will do that. But how can I access String from array I need to show it in UILabel like this      lblNamepopup.text=StringName;
    lblAddresspopup.text=StringAddress;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get index as follow

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    NSInteger index = [NameHSArray indexOfObject:marker.title];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)index);
}
```

--- EDIT ---

You can also use

- i found some reference from library.
- Note that userData should not hold any strong references to any Maps
- objects, otherwise a loop may be created (preventing ARC from releasing
  objects).

**NOTE :-**
You can pass data through snippet but snippet show data into info window. so you creates a custom info window and show data as you want.

like this,

```
NSArray * userData = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:FacilitiesHSArray[i], PhoneNoHSArray[i],FaxnoHSArray[i], nil];
NSString *userDataString = [userData componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
marker.snippet = userDataString;
```

retrive 

like this,

```
 NSString *userDataString = marker.snippet;
 NSArray *array = [userDataString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
 NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

You can Do Like this

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    // your click action

    StringAddress =  marker.snippet;
    StringName = marker.title;

    NSInteger indexCheck = [NameHSArray indexOfObject:marker.title];
    NSLog(@"Curret Index =%ld",(long)indexCheck);

    StringName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NameHSArray objectAtIndex:indexCheck]];
    StringAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AddressHSArray objectAtIndex:indexCheck]];
    StringPhoneNo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[PhoneNoHSArray objectAtIndex:indexCheck]];


    NSLog(@"Address=%@",StringAddress);
    NSLog(@"Name= %@",StringName);
    NSLog(@"Phone No =%@",StringPhoneNo);

    lblNamepopup.text=StringName;
    lblAddresspopup.text=StringAddress;
}
```

Comment: I need to get also the value of PhoneNo,FaxNo,Facility and Type from array to string.

Comment: I need to show the string in label like this      lblNamepopup.text=StringName;
    lblAddresspopup.text=StringAddress;

Comment: you need to shows a marker info window title and address.

Comment: I need to show Name,Address,PhoneNo,FaxNo,Type on UILabel by using this method -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker all in the different label now in one.

Comment: NSArray * userData = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NameHSArray[i], AddressHSArray[i],FacilitiesHSArray[i], PhoneNoHSArray[i],FaxnoHSArray[i], TypeHSArray[i], nil]; marker.userData = userData;

Comment: userData array only show last value Not what I have selected.

Comment: NSLog(@"User Data Array = %@",userData)  please provide log

Comment: I need String value in this - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {} method so that I can show it in the label.

Comment: ok @Muju i understand. provide a log of  
NSLog(@"User Data Array = %@",userData)

Comment: Medical Superintendent, ESI Hospital,
Aundh Camp, PUNE-411 007.,
NA,
020-27280985,  020-27282223, 020-27283104 ,
NA,
ESIC It is the last value of array.